# How to identify a particular Lambda instance in CloudWatch from a set of provisioned instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to specify a filter in CloudWatch Insights to get logs from a particular instance of a Lambda out of a set of provisioned instances of that Lambda. I haven't been able to find aws documentation specifying a Lambda instance identifier. Any suggestions on achieving this?

Search aws Lambda documentation for an environment variable identifying the particular Lambda instance.

Comment: Afaik each Lambda execution environment gets its own log stream, so if an existing environment is reused to process a new event (a 'warm start') then its logs will be appended to the same log stream. But ... thinking about instances seems unusual in a serverless environment such as Lambda where runtime environments are frequently torn down and replaced. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other poster that this is an implementation detail that should not concern your application.

That being said, you could create such a token yourself; lambda containers will retain their global variables throughout their lifetime. It would be trivial to create and cache a UUID, and log it to console yourself at the start of each invocation:

```
let global;

exports.handler = async () => {
  if(!global) { global = generateUUID() }
  console.log(`INSTANCE ID ${global}`)
}
```

Another option is the `log_stream_name` available in the lambda context object; it *should* be unique for each instance, and consistent across all invocations:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log(`INSTANCE ID ${context.log_stream_name}`)
}
```